# What is a good way to pass a confirmation or error message back to a view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When the user clicks the submit button on a form I want to return a success / failure message to the user and i'm wondering what the best way to send the message back to the user is.

For example on a login form if the user enters an incorrect password i'd want the view to reload with a message telling them that login failed. Or on an update form the original view they had would show up with a message saying update was successful.

My idea is to have a few partial views or HTML helpers that look for a ViewBag property like "ErrorMessage" or "SuccessMessage" and conditionally show themselves when these properties have a value. These components could be added to the _Layout or manually each form where they are required.

**Edit**

I have since found out that the **ValidationSummary** method takes a parameter of whether to exclude property errors which means you can use it to show when login / registration has failed. But there seems to be a bug where the validation summary is still generated even if there are no errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good question and one that I've been trying to solve in a new MVC application recently.  For me, ModelState.AddModelError is ok for errors but doesn't work when communicating things like success or warning messages.

Here's an approach that I decided to take recently and I welcome any feedback on it:

1. I created a class called *Notification* and an enum called *NotificationType*.  *NotificationType* has 4 values: *Success*, *Error*, *Warning*, & *Info*.  *Notification* has the properties 'Message' and 'Type'.
2. I have a static class called *NotificationManager* that holds instances of Notification objects for the life of an HttpRequest (using the user's Session object).  The idea is that any controller can add any number of *Notification* objects during the execution of an Action depending on what it needs to "tell" the user.
3. I have a custom HtmlHelper which I call once in a master page (i.e. Html.NotificationSummaryFor()) that takes a IEnumerable of Notifications (i.e. NotificationManager.Notifications) and renders a UL with child LI's for every Notification.  I then use CSS classes to style those notification LI's based on the 'NotificationType' (Red for Error, Yellow for Warning, Green for Success, etc).  The HtmlHelper is also responsible for clearing the notifications from the manager after rendering them to the View.

This implementation is pretty simple and has limitations but in general, I find that having a  framework like this ensures that a team of developers working on the same application are able to provide notifications in a consistent fashion which is important to usability and maintainability.

Comment: I really like this Rob. This was the kind of thing I was trying to nut out and you have described it really well, thanks. I like the idea that *any* page could add a notification / error etc. I'd like to know if it would extend to asynchronous events as well.

Comment: Thanks again Rob! I just implemented this and its an extremely clean solution to my problem. One thing I did slightly differently to you was have the list of notifications in the HttpContent.Current.Items collection, that way when the request is over they are automatically removed anyway. This worked well for me because I didn't want the html extension to have to clear it. But then again your way allows for the rendering to be deferred. Anyway i'm very happy with this, thanks.

Comment: I know this is old, but I was wondering are there any data concurrency issues with this suggestion? Would a singleton class be better? Just wondering, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)
This is a really easy way to set up Validation. 
Also if you are doing things like login you can do something like this where you add a modelError to the model state and then check for that in your code

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (!FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(userName , password))
                ModelState.AddModelError("" , "Incorrect username or password");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName  , false);
            return Redirect(url ?? Url.Action("Index" , "Admin"));
        } else
            return View(); //goes right back to the log on screen
```

Comment: Thanks Collin, I forgot to mention this was the way I was doing it currently. The reason I don't like this is because to show the error I then need to put: @Html.ValidationSummary() at the top of the form. That alone is fine, but I have the client side validation for each element next to the element, this means that when they leave something blank that validation error appears in the validation summary AND next to the input element.

Comment: Oh. well then maybe you could make a custom view model that includes a flag saying the validation was a success or a failure and then use a html helper to generate some output